# Ito Isometry for Brownian Bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have been looking at the following expression, and I'm a bit stuck:
$$\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dW_{u}}{1-u}(B_{1} - B_{u})\right)^{2}$$ where $\{W_{t}\}_{t\in[0,1]}$ is a standard Weiner Process and $\{B_{t}\}_{t\in[0,1]}$ is a generalized Brownian bridge (endpoints need not be the same). If I apply expectation to this, will the Ito Isometry hold? Is the resulting expression just:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}\frac{du}{(1-u)^{2}}(u - u^{2})^{2}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}u^{2}du\right]?$$ Any help or clarity is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why were you able to move the squaring inside the integral?

Comment: @LarryB. Assuming the Ito Isometry holds.

Comment: How are $W$ and $B$ related?

Comment: @John Dawkins I've been just using the fact that B is the solution to the SDE $$dB_{t} = \frac{b- B_{t}}{1-t}dt + dW_{t}.$$ However, I could also use $$B_t = (1-t)a + tb + Z_{t}$$ where $Z_{t} = W_t - tW_1$ and that would be fine.